# React Native fetch from db-models

Tags: android, react-native, reactjs

I am trying to fetch from db-models to ListView. Here is my code:

```
export default class todoDB extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dataSource : new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})
    };

}
componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchData();

}
fetchData () {
    DB.users.get_all(function(result) {
        let data = [];
        for(let i = 1; i <= result.totalrows; i++) {
            data.push(result.rows[i]);
        }
        this.setState({
            dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),

        })

    });

}
render () {
    return (
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderList}
            />
    );
}
renderList (item) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{item.age}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}};
```

After running I don`t have error or any output, only empty screen.
I using

- "react": "15.4.2",
- "react-native": "0.40.0"
- "react-native-db-models": "^0.1.3"

Comment: is ```this``` inside function(result) , still bound to the class ?

Comment: I think you have an error in `fetchData()`, in the `setState` it should be `dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)`

Comment: @kuby I think you are right, but then he should use ```prevState``` ex: ```this.setState((prevState, props) => {})``` (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested it but you could try this :

```
  fetchData() {
    DB.users.get_all((result) => {
      let data = [];
      for (let i = 1; i <= result.totalrows; i++) {
        data.push(result.rows[i]);
      }
      this.setState((prevState) => (
      {
        dataSource: prevState.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)
      }));

    });
  }
```

Changes are : using arrow function instead of `function(result)` to keep the scope of `this` and updating the previous state `prevState.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)` (in your code `dataSource` was undefined here)

As to why use `prevState`, it is to keep immutability. Little bit more info here : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate